# Element already has a logical parent. It must be detached from the old parent before it is attached to a new one"

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox, listbox

In listbox binding the values from **ItemsSource**.  If doubleclick any item from listbox, it will clear the itemsSource value it will add the combobox control to the specified **listboxselected index**. How to achieve this?

Now it shows like **"Element already has a logical parent. It must be detached from the old parent before it is attached to a new one"**

```
//Get the index value of selected Item    

 var index = lstbxindex.Items.IndexOf(lstbxindex.SelectedItem);       
   m_combobox.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
     projectInformationList = null;
        lstbxindex.ItemsSource = null;
        lstbxindex.Items.Clear(); 

   lstbxindex.Items.Insert(index, m_combobox); //InvalidOperationException thrown
   m_combobox.Focus();
```

To Remove the Items from list I used this code,

```
 IEditableCollectionView items = lstbxindex.Items;
            if (items.CanRemove)
            {
                items.Remove(lstbxindex.SelectedItem);
            }
```

I don't know how to add the control in listbox selectedindex while itemsSource is in use.

I tried ->
`listbox.Items.Add(combox);` it shows, can't able to add items while itemsSource is in use but in this code I didn't mention the selected index. But I want to add a control for listbox selectedindex position while double click any items from listbox.

Edit

I tried to add the items without using itemsSource like,

```
foreach (DTorow rowdata in table.Rows)
    { 
      lstbox.Items.Add(rowdata .Name);

      }
```

But it did not show the values in listbox. If it is shows the value in listbox simply add a combobox into specified index using this code `listbox.Items.Insert(0"combobox)` it will not shows invalidException(itemsSource is in use can't able to add new item).

Comment: So your actual goal is to show a ComboBox instead of text when an item in a ListBox is selected?

Comment: @Clemens Yes Exactly

Comment: Could you also explain what the ComboBox is supposed to do? Should it select from a set of options, where the choosen option would be displayed when the ListBox item is not selected?

Comment: @Clemens Initially listbox loaded items with the help of itemsSource. I need to edit the listbox item value using combobox. So when I doubleclick the listboxitem it will add the combobox to appropriate index and modify the listboxitem value and click enter it will add the listboxitem and combobox will hidden. if there is no change in listboxitem simply click esc the listbox selecteditem remain same in listbox combobox will hidden.

Comment: Throw away all your code and do it using WPF standards. See my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple example of how to do it with the standard WPF approach, i.e. MVVM and data templating. As already said in a comment to your previous question, you'll have to read the [Data Binding Overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/data/data-binding-overview) and [Data Templating Overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/data/data-templating-overview) articles to understand it, but this is unavoidable if you want to learn WPF.

The view model and the MainWindow code behind:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        var vm = new ViewModel();

        vm.Items.Add(new DataItem { Text = "Item 1" });
        vm.Items.Add(new DataItem { Text = "Item 2" });
        vm.Items.Add(new DataItem { Text = "Item 3" });
        vm.Items.Add(new DataItem { Text = "Item 4" });

        DataContext = vm;
    }
}

public class DataItem : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private string text;
    public string Text
    {
        get { return text; }
        set
        {
            text = value;
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(Text)));
        }
    }
}

public class ViewModel
{
    public ObservableCollection<DataItem> Items { get; }
        = new ObservableCollection<DataItem>();
}
```

And the XAML with two different ControlTemplates of a ListBoxItem, depending on 
whether it's selected or not:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
    <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                        <TextBlock Margin="5,3" Text="{Binding Text}"/>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Template">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                                <TextBox Text="{Binding Text}"/>
                            </ControlTemplate>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
</ListBox>
```

Comment: Thankyou I got a idea from your code. I'm facing issue in how to trigger event when doubleclik the listboxitem.?

Comment: That's impractical. How would you get rid of the ComboBox, another double click?

Comment: I don't need a any load items in comboBox. Simply Rename listbox selected items with the help combobox or textbox. ComboBox or TextBox will appear while doubleclik the listbox item.

Comment: You mean you just want to have an editable text element? Take a look at the DataGrid control.

Comment: I have simplified the example to use a TextBox instead of a ComboBox.

Comment: Sir I want to add a textbox while doubleclick the selectedItems in LitsBox.

Comment: TextBox is not able to access in codebehind if it is access I will make visibility Hidden for the textbox after editing.

Comment: On which event? How do you detect that editing has ended?

Comment: At the time of enter Key press. textbox items updated  to listboxitem.

Comment: You may add an `IsEditing` property to the DataItem class and change the ControlTemplate by a DataTrigger instead of a Trigger, e.g. `<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsEditing}" Value="True">`. Then you can set and reset the IsEditing property however you like in code behind.

Comment: I have doubt in Where to set the listboxitem doubleclick event? like  `<EventSetter Event="MouseDoubleClick" Handler="HandleDoubleClick" /> `

Comment: Right, add that EventSetter to the ListBoxItem Style, and make sure there is an appropriate HandleDoubleClick method in code behind.

Comment: How to add EventSetter to the ListBoxItem Style. `   <ListBoxItem.Style Event="MouseDoubleClick" Handler="HandleDoubleClick" >`

Comment: Just like the other Setter, for the Template property. Please read the online documentation that I've linked in the answer.